# Changing Color of Text in Text box depending on value of text box

Tags: c#

I am trying to change the color of the text inside of a text box depending on weather they are connected to my VPN or not. Lime if they are connected & the their public ip matches the server ip. Then Red if their public ip does not match. This is the code I have

```
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (checkBox1.Checked)//this is working
            {
                Uri ad = new Uri("https://icanhazip.com/");
                WebClient web = new WebClient();
                PublicIP.Text = web.DownloadString(ad);

            }
            else if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
            {
                PublicIP.Text = "";
            }
        }

        private void PublicIP_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connect = "142.44.240.187";

            if (PublicIP.Text == connect)
            {
                PublicIP.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
            }
            else 
            {
                PublicIP.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

    }
```

It only Shows up as red even when I am connected. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Obviously the `Text` value is never equal to the local variable value that you've included. Why this would be, no one can say, as you have neglected to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please explain why you expect the value returned by `web.DownloadString(ad);` to be the IP address you're comparing to.

Comment: Make 2 textboxes and set one to `ForeColor` to `Lime` and the other to `Red` without any conditions. Does it work? If yes, then you know this works so start looking at the rest of your code such as `if (PublicIP.Text == connect)` etc. and find out what's wrong with them.

Answer (score 0):

PublicIP_TextChanged seems trigger when your "Text change!", so maybe your text always is "142.44.240.187" never change, it should not work. Or your connect is not "142.44.240.187", it becomes go into else(red).

I think if you can run the debug mode and add a break point at this if condition, then you may get what you want?